# Create data with multiple nested attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, orm

I am trying to create an `item` with nested attributes, these are my tables:

**Item**

```
has_many :items_modifier_groups, dependent: :destroy
has_many :items_modifier_group_items, dependent: :destroy

attr_accessible :items_modifier_groups_attributes, :items_modifier_group_items_attributes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :items_modifier_groups, :items_modifier_group_items
```

**ModifierGroup**

```
attr_accessible: tag_id
```

**ItemsModifierGroup**

```
belongs_to :modifier_group
belongs_to :item
has_many :items_modifier_group_items, dependent: :destroy

attr_accessible :item_id, :modifier_group_id, :modifier_group_attributes, :items_modifier_group_items_attributes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :modifier_group, :items_modifier_group_items
```

**ItemsModifierGroupItem - Table4**

```
belongs_to :items_modifier_group
belongs_to :item

attr_accessible :items_modifier_group_id, :item_id, :pre_select
```

Params to create from console:

```
c = Item.new(
  "name" => "test1", "items_modifier_groups_attributes"=> { 
    "0"=> { 
      "items_modifier_group_items_attributes"=> {
        "0"=> {
          "pre_select"=>"true"
        }
      }, 
      "min_item"=>"1", 
      "modifier_group_attributes"=> { 
        "tag_id"=> "5" 
      }
    }
  }
)

c.save

INSERT INTO "items_modifier_group_items" ("created_at", "item_id", "items_modifier_group_id", "pre_select", "sequence_no", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Wed, 28 Feb 2018 15:44:27 GST +04:00], ["item_id", nil], ["items_modifier_group_id", 35], ["pre_select", true], ["sequence_no", 0], ["updated_at", Wed, 28 Feb 2018 15:44:27 GST +04:00]
```

When it creates an item from **CONSOLE**, the `item_id` is `nil` in `ItemsModifierGroupItem` table; however, `item_id` is created in `ItemsModifierGroup` table.

Am I missing anything in the params?

Comment: its working perfectly fine as whenever you create an object with associated object it automatically fetch the associated object id.

Comment: But the item_id is not getting in the ItemsModifierGroupItem table

Comment: it will automatically save item_id with nested attributes as you have association belongs_to and has_many

Comment: Yes normally this was happening but here INSERT INTO "items_modifier_group_items" ("created_at", "item_id", "items_modifier_group_id", "pre_select", "sequence_no", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Wed, 28 Feb 2018 15:44:27 GST +04:00], ["item_id", nil], ["items_modifier_group_id", 35], ["pre_select", true], ["sequence_no", 0], ["updated_at", Wed, 28 Feb 2018 15:44:27 GST +04:00]] item_id is nil

Comment: Show us your controller, you might have setup the branching relationship calls wrong.

Comment: All that i have mentioned in the model here

Comment: Then that's the answer, if all you have is what you posted there, you're missing a rails controller to direct the app.

Comment: But it should work when we do it through console right?